# Update price from table for a period of time

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to update a price from table based on a condition(barcode of product), but I am having problem to update prices of products for a period of time. For example I update price(0.45-> 0.43) of product(2233-Coca Cola 0.33 ml), but i want this update to be available for a period of time (for example from date 23 until date 28) and after this date , the price to be back to its original state

I use this code to update price

```
    Create procedure edittheprice
    @price float,
    @barcode int

    as

   update tblproducts set Price=@prices where Barcode = @barcode
```

Thanks to everyone

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Microsoft SQL 2008 R2

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this is more of a data model issue than stored procedure. since the new price is periodic, a separate table will be helpful. For example, a discount_prices table as below:

```
product_id | discounted_price | valid_from | valid_to
```

Joining this with the product table helps you know current actual price and will also help you track the prices over time.